# How to select all users data, Ionic Firebase

Tags: typescript, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database

I have usersProfile table, where save data by uid

[image]

How to select all users uid and data?
I can select only Authorized users data.

```
getUsersData(token: string) {
    const userId = this.authService.getActiveUser().uid;
    return this.http.get('https://mainapp.firebaseio.com/usersProfile/' + userId + '.json?auth=' + token)
        .map((response: Response) => {
            const usersData: UsersData[] = response.json() ? response.json(): [];                
            return usersData;
        })    
        .do((userData : UsersData[]) => {
            if (userData) {
                this.usersData = userData;
            }
            else {
                this.usersData = [];                
            }
        })
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want use firebase you must read this [article first](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/start). First of all you need add firebase to your Ionic project and 
Installation & Setup in JavaScript initialize the realtime database JavaScript SDK.

Just do `npm install firebase`

In your app.module.ts create firebase config object:

```
// Set the configuration for your app
// TODO: Replace with your project's config object
var config = {
  apiKey: "apiKey",
  authDomain: "projectId.firebaseapp.com",
  databaseURL: "https://databaseName.firebaseio.com",
  storageBucket: "bucket.appspot.com"
};
firebase.initializeApp(config);

// Get a reference to the database service
var database = firebase.database();
```

You could find all setting in your [Firebase console](https://console.firebase.google.com). For more information read Firebase documentation.

After that inside you angular service you could import firebase and do request to database:

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase';

// Service declaration here
// code here ...

getUsersData() {
    const userId = this.firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
    return firebase.database().ref('usersProfile')
                            .once('value')        
                            .then(snapshot => snapshot.val())    
                            .then(users => console.log(users));
}
```

More information you could find [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#read_data_once)