# get all user from firebase to own backend

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I'm trying using google login+firebase for my ionic 4 app, all users are in firebase but can i get user information to my own backend? What I mean by that is I also build admin panel for me to display all of information that I get in my ionic apps also display in my admin panel.

Here's my code:

```
login() {
    this.googlePlus.login({
      webClientId : '927898787134-spvfdmvm9apq0e1fo2efvvura8vqpid8.apps.googleusercontent.com',
      offline : true
    }).then(res => {
      firebase.auth().signInWithCredential(firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.credential(res.idToken))
      .then(suc => {
        // console.log('users', JSON.stringify(suc));
        this.httpwelcome.post('https://mobile.youthscarf.id/ionic/login_data.php', { userData: res.userData, user: res.user, displayName: res.displayName, email: res.email}).subscribe((response) => {
           console.log(response);
           console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
         });
        localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(suc));
      }).catch(ns => {
        console.log('Unsucessful');
      });
    });
  }
```

I was trying to use http post but seems to be not working. Anyone knows how to achieve that?

Comment: Why you are make two copy of database in firebase as well in our server as well. You can make admin panel in angular and you can read firebase database from angular itself

Comment: This may be related to that solved issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45391075/how-to-select-all-users-data-ionic-firebase

Comment: My admin panel is using php, because it's for my client they don't have knowledge to access firebase so i think it would be easy if i give them an admin panel. and of course it's not only for display user but changing all of the content inside my app